Getting the error when using the actions/checkout@v4 in selfhosted foregejo instance "stat /data/.cache/act/actions-checkout@v4: not a directory"
Comment
Refered the document - https://forgejo.org/docs/latest/admin/actions/ for setting up the actions. All the stuffs are working properly but when action is trigger then on the checkout step it is showing this error. Logs attached below..
image1
Runner-1(version:v3.4.1) received task 9 of job 5, be triggered by event: push
workflow prepared
evaluating expression 'success()'
expression 'success()' evaluated to 'true'
  Start image=node:16-bullseye
    docker pull image=node:16-bullseye platform= username= forcePull=false
    docker pull node:16-bullseye
Image exists? true
[{bridge 810232c32b5b314ce51f3bff9ab9e924e0e7980bdfc8450585aa8d96a06427ba 2024-10-04 16:21:01.123196988 +0000 UTC local bridge false {default map[] [{172.17.0.0/16  172.17.0.1 map[]}]} false false false {} false map[] map[com.docker.network.bridge.default_bridge:true com.docker.network.bridge.enable_icc:true com.docker.network.bridge.enable_ip_masquerade:true com.docker.network.bridge.host_binding_ipv4:0.0.0.0 com.docker.network.bridge.name:docker0 com.docker.network.driver.mtu:1500] map[] [] map[]} {none 8a1d0ce839f049b8ed20cff704521a5512687bece8e314f50f3df8727bfa5320 2024-10-04 16:21:01.031023229 +0000 UTC local null false {default map[] []} false false false {} false map[] map[] map[] [] map[]} {host 70568f494c440a95bf61a5b69b1c1dacb4ffa02dbd1ad2d5b4a4095814ba9292 2024-10-04 16:21:01.065820346 +0000 UTC local host false {default map[] []} false false false {} false map[] map[] map[] [] map[]}]
    docker create image=node:16-bullseye platform= entrypoint=["tail" "-f" "/dev/null"] cmd=[] network="GITEA-ACTIONS-TASK-9_WORKFLOW-Test-Docker-Build_JOB-test-docker-build-test_docker_build-network"
Common container.Config ==> &{Hostname: Domainname: User: AttachStdin:false AttachStdout:false AttachStderr:false ExposedPorts:map[] Tty:false OpenStdin:false StdinOnce:false Env:[RUNNER_TOOL_CACHE=/opt/hostedtoolcache RUNNER_OS=Linux RUNNER_ARCH=X64 RUNNER_TEMP=/tmp LANG=C.UTF-8] Cmd:[] Healthcheck:<nil> ArgsEscaped:false Image:node:16-bullseye Volumes:map[] WorkingDir:/workspace/IskconNoida/iic Entrypoint:[] NetworkDisabled:false MacAddress: OnBuild:[] Labels:map[] StopSignal: StopTimeout:<nil> Shell:[]}
Common container.HostConfig ==> &{Binds:[] ContainerIDFile: LogConfig:{Type: Config:map[]} NetworkMode:GITEA-ACTIONS-TASK-9_WORKFLOW-Test-Docker-Build_JOB-test-docker-build-test_docker_build-network PortBindings:map[] RestartPolicy:{Name: MaximumRetryCount:0} AutoRemove:true VolumeDriver: VolumesFrom:[] ConsoleSize:[0 0] Annotations:map[] CapAdd:[] CapDrop:[] CgroupnsMode: DNS:[] DNSOptions:[] DNSSearch:[] ExtraHosts:[] GroupAdd:[] IpcMode: Cgroup: Links:[] OomScoreAdj:0 PidMode: Privileged:false PublishAllPorts:false ReadonlyRootfs:false SecurityOpt:[] StorageOpt:map[] Tmpfs:map[] UTSMode: UsernsMode: ShmSize:0 Sysc***:map[] Runtime: Isolation: Resources:{CPUShares:0 Memory:0 NanoCPUs:0 CgroupParent: BlkioWeight:0 BlkioWeightDevice:[] BlkioDeviceReadBps:[] BlkioDeviceWriteBps:[] BlkioDeviceReadIOps:[] BlkioDeviceWriteIOps:[] CPUPeriod:0 CPUQuota:0 CPURealtimePeriod:0 CPURealtimeRuntime:0 CpusetCpus: CpusetMems: Devices:[] DeviceCgroupRules:[] DeviceRequests:[] KernelMemory:0 KernelMemoryTCP:0 MemoryReservation:0 MemorySwap:0 MemorySwappiness:<nil> OomKillDisable:<nil> PidsLimit:<nil> Ulimits:[] CPUCount:0 CPUPercent:0 IOMaximumIOps:0 IOMaximumBandwidth:0} Mounts:[{Type:volume Source:GITEA-ACTIONS-TASK-9_WORKFLOW-Test-Docker-Build_JOB-test-docker-build Target:/workspace/IskconNoida/iic ReadOnly:false Consistency: BindOptions:<nil> VolumeOptions:<nil> TmpfsOptions:<nil> ClusterOptions:<nil>} {Type:volume Source:act-toolcache Target:/opt/hostedtoolcache ReadOnly:false Consistency: BindOptions:<nil> VolumeOptions:<nil> TmpfsOptions:<nil> ClusterOptions:<nil>} {Type:volume Source:GITEA-ACTIONS-TASK-9_WORKFLOW-Test-Docker-Build_JOB-test-docker-build-env Target:/var/run/act ReadOnly:false Consistency: BindOptions:<nil> VolumeOptions:<nil> TmpfsOptions:<nil> ClusterOptions:<nil>}] MaskedPaths:[] ReadonlyPaths:[] Init:<nil>}
input.NetworkAliases ==> [test_docker_build]
Created container name=GITEA-ACTIONS-TASK-9_WORKFLOW-Test-Docker-Build_JOB-test-docker-build id=67386fd79c2802fd7f128dc2e4a2f290cec777c20f00a019b4f797da2aadfb62 from image node:16-bullseye (platform: )
ENV ==> [RUNNER_TOOL_CACHE=/opt/hostedtoolcache RUNNER_OS=Linux RUNNER_ARCH=X64 RUNNER_TEMP=/tmp LANG=C.UTF-8]
    docker run image=node:16-bullseye platform= entrypoint=["tail" "-f" "/dev/null"] cmd=[] network="GITEA-ACTIONS-TASK-9_WORKFLOW-Test-Docker-Build_JOB-test-docker-build-test_docker_build-network"
Starting container: 67386fd79c2802fd7f128dc2e4a2f290cec777c20f00a019b4f797da2aadfb62
Started container: 67386fd79c2802fd7f128dc2e4a2f290cec777c20f00a019b4f797da2aadfb62
Writing entry to tarball workflow/event.json len:4888
Writing entry to tarball workflow/envs.txt len:0
Extracting content to '/var/run/act/'
  ☁  git clone 'https://code.forgejo.org/actions/checkout' # ref=v4
  cloning https://code.forgejo.org/actions/checkout to /data/.cache/act/actions-checkout@v4
Unable to clone https://code.forgejo.org/actions/checkout refs/heads/v4: stat /data/.cache/act/actions-checkout@v4: not a directory
stat /data/.cache/act/actions-checkout@v4: not a directory
skipping post step for 'Checkout'; step was not executed
Cleaning up container for job test_docker_build
Removed container: 67386fd79c2802fd7f128dc2e4a2f290cec777c20f00a019b4f797da2aadfb62
    docker volume rm GITEA-ACTIONS-TASK-9_WORKFLOW-Test-Docker-Build_JOB-test-docker-build
    docker volume rm GITEA-ACTIONS-TASK-9_WORKFLOW-Test-Docker-Build_JOB-test-docker-build-env
Cleaning up network for job test_docker_build, and network name is: GITEA-ACTIONS-TASK-9_WORKFLOW-Test-Docker-Build_JOB-test-docker-build-test_docker_build-network
[{none 8a1d0ce839f049b8ed20cff704521a5512687bece8e314f50f3df8727bfa5320 2024-10-04 16:21:01.031023229 +0000 UTC local null false {default map[] []} false false false {} false map[] map[] map[] [] map[]} {host 70568f494c440a95bf61a5b69b1c1dacb4ffa02dbd1ad2d5b4a4095814ba9292 2024-10-04 16:21:01.065820346 +0000 UTC local host false {default map[] []} false false false {} false map[] map[] map[] [] map[]} {bridge 810232c32b5b314ce51f3bff9ab9e924e0e7980bdfc8450585aa8d96a06427ba 2024-10-04 16:21:01.123196988 +0000 UTC local bridge false {default map[] [{172.17.0.0/16  172.17.0.1 map[]}]} false false false {} false map[] map[com.docker.network.bridge.default_bridge:true com.docker.network.bridge.enable_icc:true com.docker.network.bridge.enable_ip_masquerade:true com.docker.network.bridge.host_binding_ipv4:0.0.0.0 com.docker.network.bridge.name:docker0 com.docker.network.driver.mtu:1500] map[] [] map[]} {GITEA-ACTIONS-TASK-9_WORKFLOW-Test-Docker-Build_JOB-test-docker-build-test_docker_build-network 237ca9cda953da508511fe4abd41e415d797ec3a2568bda84fd819f6cae13906 2024-10-04 16:35:52.72045701 +0000 UTC local bridge false {default map[] [{172.19.0.0/16  172.19.0.1 map[]}]} false false false {} false map[] map[] map[] [] map[]}]
  Job failed
stat /data/.cache/act/actions-checkout@v4: not a directory

And here are the action.yml file

name: Test Docker Build

on:
  push:
    branches:
    - main
    - development

  pull_request:
    branches:
    - main
    - development
  
jobs:
  test_docker_build:
    timeout-minutes: 10
    runs-on: docker

    steps:
    # Check out the repository
    - name: Checkout
      uses: actions/checkout@v4

    - name: Start Containers
      run: |
        DB_CONNECTION = "${{ secrets.IIC_DB_CONNECTION }}" \
        DB_HOST = "${{ secrets.IIC_DB_HOST }}" \
        DB_DATABASE = "${{ secrets.IIC_DB_DATABASE }}" \
        DB_USERNAME = "${{ secrets.IIC_DB_USERNAME }}" \
        DB_PASSWORD = "${{ secrets.IIC_DB_PASSWORD }}" \
        docker-compose --profile stage -f "docker-compose.yml" up -d --build        

    - name: Stop containers
      if: always()
      run: docker-compose --profile stage -f "docker-compose.yml" down

Here are the forgejo app.ini -
APP_NAME = Personal git
RUN_MODE = prod
APP_SLOGAN = Git
RUN_USER = git
WORK_PATH = /data/gitea

[repository]
ROOT = /data/git/repositories

[repository.local]
LOCAL_COPY_PATH = /data/gitea/tmp/local-repo

[repository.upload]
TEMP_PATH = /data/gitea/uploads

[server]
APP_DATA_PATH = /data/gitea
DOMAIN = git.personal.com
SSH_DOMAIN = git.personal.com
HTTP_PORT = 3000
ROOT_URL = https://git.personal.com/
DISABLE_SSH = false
SSH_PORT = 22
SSH_LISTEN_PORT = 22
LFS_START_SERVER = true
LFS_JWT_SECRET = some_secret_here
OFFLINE_MODE = true

[database]
PATH = /data/gitea/gitea.db
DB_TYPE = mysql
HOST = host
NAME = name
USER = user
PASSWD = password
LOG_SQL = false
SCHEMA = 
SSL_MODE = disable

[indexer]
ISSUE_INDEXER_PATH = /data/gitea/indexers/issues.bleve

[session]
PROVIDER_CONFIG = /data/gitea/sessions
PROVIDER = file

[picture]
AVATAR_UPLOAD_PATH = /data/gitea/avatars
REPOSITORY_AVATAR_UPLOAD_PATH = /data/gitea/repo-avatars

[attachment]
PATH = /data/gitea/attachments

[log]
MODE = console
LEVEL = info
ROOT_PATH = /data/gitea/log

[security]
INSTALL_LOCK = true
SECRET_KEY = 
REVERSE_PROXY_LIMIT = 1
REVERSE_PROXY_TRUSTED_PROXIES = *
INTERNAL_TOKEN = some_internal_token_here
PASSWORD_HASH_ALGO = pass_algo

[service]
DISABLE_REGISTRATION = true
REQUIRE_SIGNIN_VIEW = false
REGISTER_EMAIL_CONFIRM = true
ENABLE_NOTIFY_MAIL = true
ALLOW_ONLY_EXTERNAL_REGISTRATION = false
ENABLE_CAPTCHA = false
DEFAULT_KEEP_EMAIL_PRIVATE = false
DEFAULT_ALLOW_CREATE_ORGANIZATION = true
DEFAULT_ENABLE_TIMETRACKING = true
NO_REPLY_ADDRESS = noreply.localhost

[lfs]
PATH = /data/git/lfs

[mailer]
ENABLED = true
SMTP_ADDR = smtp.google.com
SMTP_PORT = 465
FROM = frommail
USER = user
PASSWD = 'test'

[openid]
ENABLE_OPENID_SIGNIN = true
ENABLE_OPENID_SIGNUP = true

[cron.update_checker]
ENABLED = true

[repository.pull-request]
DEFAULT_MERGE_STYLE = merge

[repository.signing]
DEFAULT_TRUST_MODEL = committer

[oauth2]
JWT_SECRET = some_token_here

[actions]
ENABLED = true
DEFAULT_ACTIONS_URL = https://code.forgejo.org


I tried the github actions it's cool but there is some limitation in build time and storage in github actions. So, I'm using the self hosted forgejo instance and setted up all the things for the personal use but there is an error in the actions. I wanted to know that how i can use these actions that defined in the github actions or forgejo actions in self hosted forgejo.
